# MySQL query uses filesort despite index when ordering

Tags: mysql, sql, join, indexing

**Edit:**
I made query it simpler just to test:

```
select *
from table1 where date >= '2012-02-02' order by date, col_2 desc
```

I have composite index on date and col_2 however when I do explain on my query it shows:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys            | key             | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1           | range | col_2_date, date         | col_2_date      | 4       | NULL | 4643 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+--------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Why does mySQL use filesort if I have index on the columns col_2 and date and how could I prevent it?

Comment: You don't have an index on the date.. How else do you expect it to sort it? (Doesn't look like the correct date col is indexed)

Comment: Is the composite index really `(date, col_2)` and not `(col_2, date)` as its name suggests?

Comment: Even with composite index, the wanted order by is `date ASC, col_2 DESC`. The index can be used for `ASC, ASC` or `DESC, DESC` ordering, not mixed.

Comment: Ive tried ordering by both "date, col_2 desc" and "col_2, date desc" and the result is same.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY col_2 DESC, date DESC` if your index is `(col_2, date)`

Comment: Thank you @ypercube it worked like charm! Could you post your comment as answer so I could accept it and vote it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to order your results in the same order youve created your index ..e.g.
if index is (col_1, col_2) then use `... order by col_1 desc, col_2 desc` or `... order by col_1 asc, col_2 asc` and not `... order by col_1 asc, col_2 desc` or `order by col_2, col_1` for example.